# Installing Windows 7 alongside LVM - encrypted Xubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, xubuntu, encryption, lvm

I have recently bought a new laptop and installed Xubuntu 15.04 on it right away. I store some sensitive data on it, so I checked the "Encrypt the new Xubuntu installation for security" and "Use LVM with the new Xubuntu installation". Then I found out that many games I like don't work with Wine, so I decided to install Windows 7 as dual-boot.

My question is - can this be done simply by resizing the Xubuntu partition and installing Windows on a new NTFS one? Or would this require backing up all the data, formatting the drive and reinstalling Xubuntu unencrypted, then Windows?

Answer (score 0):

You can install W7 without lose any data... just resize the Xubuntu partition using Disks utility and creating a new NTFS one.

Once you install W7, probably you won't be able to boot Xubuntu; don't dismay: this can be fixed with EasyBCD (http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) adding a new entry for Xubuntu (selecting GRUB2) and aiming to the ext4 partition where Linux is installed, and you can even decide what OS will be the default option. Don't be afraid, just make a backup of the MBR... EasyBCD allows you to. It have a very intuitive interface. You won't have any problem to use it, I hope.

It can happen, too, that some crazy future update on Xubuntu restore de GRUB2 original boot... then you won't be able to boot Windows; once again, don't dismay: this can be fixed using Lilo...

```
sudo apt-get install lilo
sudo lilo -M /dev/sda mbr
```

Of course, you must be sure that your hard disk is /dev/sda.

Abraham Medina.